# Comparing a formatted string with an int

Tags: c, algorithm, types, formatting

I have the following in c:

```
printf("(Type %d)\n", t[0].type); // displays: (Type 4)
```

I need to do a comparaison to check if `t[0].type` is 3, 4, or 5.

```
if (t[0].type == 4) { //code }
```

But it doesn't work since `t[0].type` is a `char` read from binary file.

I tried converting `t[0].type` to int with `t[0].type - '0'` then comparing but it didn't work neither. How to do that ?

Comment: If `t[0].type` displays 4, the comparison should work.

Comment: @Klas: that's incorrect.  `char` (and `short`) datatypes are always promoted to `int` when they are called as variadic parameters.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
if ( t[0].type == '4') {...}
```

Comment: But he said integer value of `t[0].type` is 4, by the output of the printf statement

Comment: ... this can be expressed directly as `if (t[0].type == '4')`

Answer (score 0):

Strange. How can following code

```
printf("(Type %d)\n", t[0].type);
```

display "Type 4", if there is stored '4' (char)?

```
char x;
x = '4';

printf( "%d\n", x ); /*This will output 52*/
```

So, you can use the conversion

```
if( x - '0' == 4 ){...}
```

and it should work just fine

Answer (score 0):

atoi()/ itoa() function should help as well
OR look at the [ASCII Table](http://www.asciitable.com/). If you subtract 48 (ascii code for '0') from your variable you end up with it's integer value.

```
     if(([0].type - 48) == 4)
OR
     if((t[0].type - '0')== 4)
```

Whichever you like.